# Establish WiFi network at my university dormitories

Tags: networking

In my apartment I have access to the university LAN. When any computer is connected to the LAN (by wire) a registration page appears in the browser, and I need to input my university username and password in order to get access to the Internet.

Is there any option to configure the router to complete this authentication process for me, filling out my details automatically?

Comment: Make sure it's not against your housing agreement to have a wifi network. Many universities prohibit any sort of router being attached to their LAN.

Comment: I checked, there isn't any housing agreement violation.

Comment: What exactly triggers the login page to appear? Opening a web browser?

Comment: Yes exactly....